# 2007 S40 - Accessory Delay (5 secs) when turning the Key to Position II

Tags: electrical, volvo, ignition

My son's 2007 S40 has an accessory delay of 5 (secs).  The lights and indicators ultimately come on.  The car has no problem starting and runs nice.  The dealer says it needs a new ignition.  An independent shop believes it is the CEM.  Is there a relay specifically for the ignition?  Could the antenna ring not contacting correctly?

In addition, the shop needed to download some software to the car but the computer wouldn't allow it because it stated that the key wasn't in the right position - but it was in position II.  Any help greatly appreciated...a new CEM is $800.

Answer (score 2):

Might be the [CEM](http://volvoforums.org.uk/showthread.php?t=67584), if it has anything to do with the instrument cluster.  Might just be the wiring, as was the case [here](http://www.volvoforums.org.uk/showthread.php?t=67437).  Though not being able to flash your powertrain controller due to the key position seems to point to the ignition cylinder or some of the wiring to it.

If you really do have a CEM fault, you can see if you can find a wholesale source for it, though your shop(s) might refuse to install parts you don't buy from them (or if they do the install, they might not warranty the work).  There's always the junkyard, too, but going that route you don't know if you're getting a good part, and the shop probably won't want to install a used part given that new parts are available.  Usually, if you're paying for labor, junkyard parts don't make sense, but if you need a Volvo CEM, maybe.  It doesn't look that it's that hard to swap out, you might even be able to do it yourself.